# Use Jenkins to compare files in two nodes

Tags: jenkins

I wonder are there features for jenkins to capture the result /data in a node and persist it in master.

I come up with the scenario that I need to check some folders in two machines to see whether they have same no of files & same size.

If hudson can save some result like "ls -ltR" in master , then I can gather at both node the results in two jobs then compare.

Are there any elegant solution to this simple problem?

currently I can connect two machines to each other via SSH and solve the problem, while this connection is not always available.
(With SSH I believe the best way is to use rsync -an /path/to/ hostB:/path/to/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple problem, only slightly elegant solution :

1. Write a simple job `listdir` which does `DIR > C:\logs\list1.txt .. list`
2. Go to `Post-build Actions`
3. Add `Archive the artifacts` for example from above:  `C:\logs\*.*`
4. Now run a build and go to `http://jenkinsservername:8080/job/listdir/`
5. You'll see the `list1.txt` which you can click on, and see the contents.

   I have given a Windows example, you can of course replace `DIR` with `ls -ltr`

Answer (score 1):

Or use archive artifacts in combination with the [Copy Artifacts Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Copy+Artifact+Plugin) to pull the result of another job in the job where the comparison shall be done.